# removing repeating lines from the file

Tags: linux

which is the simplest way to remove:

1. appearances of the single line series in a row
2. appearances of the double line series in a row
3. appearances of the triple line series in a row

according to example? Is it possible to solve this using Linux script?
thank you
P.

Input file:

```
text1
text2
text3
text1
text2
text3
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text4
text5
text1
text1
text4
text5
text4
text5
text4
text5
text4
text5
text4
text5
text1
text3
```

Output file:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text1
text4
text5
text1
text3
```

Comment: This is surely possible. What did you try?

Comment: The question is very unclear, but I think you mean the following...  Find blocks of 3 or 2 or 1 lines of text that are repeated adjacently and retain only the first instance each time.  Is that right?